# How to set global date format in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using **Thymeleaf** to generate a *JSON* reply in a *Spring REST controller*. Thymeleaf is invoked this way:

```
  Context context = new Context(Locale.getDefault(), document);
  String result = templateEngine.process("xxx", context);
```

The template mode is set to **JAVASCRIPT**.

The dates are output like this: "`2018-01-31T00:00:00.000+01:00`".
I'd like to drop the milliseconds and time zone, so the dates are output like this: "`2018-01-31T00:00:00`". I can use `#dates.format` on each date, but there are a lot of dates, so I'd like to set a global format for dates. There has to be a simple way to do this?

**Note:** I'm using Java 8 but the source dates are `java.util.Date` objects and I have no control over this.